# ActiveSupport::Concern ClassMethod not being attached to host class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in `models/concerns/sluggable.rb`:

```
module Sluggable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def sluggify(str, type)
            # ...
        end     
    end
end
```

And I've included it in `models/slug.rb:`

```
class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Sluggable
    # ...
    before_save :create_slug

    private
        def create_slug
            self.slug = Slug.sluggify(self.title, 'item')
        end
end
```

I'm under the impression that the `sluggify` method from the module should now be available as a class method of `Slug` but it appears to not be the case. I get an `undefined method: sluggify` error when trying to insert the model into the database.

The `Sluggable` module is available from the Rails console. And I can confirm that my code is correct:

```
module Sluggable
    def sluggify(str, type)
        # ...
    end
end

class SluggableTest
    extend Sluggable
end

slug = SluggableTest.sluggify('string to sluggify', 'item')
```

So why can't I get it to work as a concern inside the model?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `include Sluggable` on the top of the `Slug` class like this:

```
  class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Sluggable
    # ...
    before_save :create_slug

    private

    def create_slug
      self.slug = Slug.sluggify(self.title, 'item')
    end
  end
```

Because, you are right. `sluggify` method will be attached to the `Slug` class once you `include` the `Sluggable` module in the `Slug` class and will be available as a class method of the `Slug` class. I think, because you don't have `include Sluggable` on top of your `Slug` class, the `sluggify` method is being called before the `Sluggable` module is included into the `Slug` class and hence it's getting and `undefined method` error, which makes sense!

Comment: This is not working. I'm still getting the same `undefined method 'sluggify'` error. This is weird! What else could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Yeah, it's very weird. I don't see any other issue in your posted code :(

Comment: I finally got it working though I moved the module to the `/lib` folder, configured the folder for autoloading and finally extended the module inside the Slug model class without using `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Thanks for your time, man.

Answer (score 0):

you define your method inside nested module, but doesn't include it or extend it. Following is the right template:

```
module Sluggable
  module ClassMethods

  end

  module InstanceMethods

  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend         ClassMethods
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end
end
```